# Не могу понять, почему некорректно работает функция pop

Tags: python, python-3.x

Написал функцию, которая должна убирать из списка единично встречающиеся цифры.

```
def checkio(data: list) -> list:
    output = data
    for i in range(len(data)):
        if data.count(data[i]) == 1:
            output.pop(output.index(data[i]))
    return output
```

При запуске с такими аргументами `checkio([1,2,3,1,3])` выдает ошибку

`IndexError: list index out of range`

Методом проб и ошибок пришел к выводу, что если во второй строке добавить функцию `list()`, то все начинает работать корректно.

```
def checkio(data: list) -> list:
    output = list(data)
    for i in range(len(data)):
        if data.count(data[i]) == 1:
            output.pop(output.index(data[i]))
    return output
```

Не могу понять в чем проблем. Ведь и data и output имеют вид list без каких-либо дополнительных уточнений. Почему же требует указывать, что output = list(data), а просто output = data не работает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Присвоение в Python не приводит к копированию объекта:

```
$ python
@>>> a = list(range(5))
@>>> a
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
@>>> b = a
@>>> a is b
True
@>>> b.pop(2)
2
@>>> b
[0, 1, 3, 4]
@>>> a
[0, 1, 3, 4]
```

Видно что `a` и `b` ссылаются на один и тот же объект. Если вызвать `list` то будет создана копия:

```
$ python
@>>> a = list(range(5))
@>>> a
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
@>>> b = list(a)
@>>> a is b
False
@>>> b.pop(2)
2
@>>> b
[0, 1, 3, 4]
@>>> a
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Возвращаясь к вашей задаче. Если вы хотите создать модифицированную копию списка вам нужен `list comprehension`. Чтобы не пересчитывать элементы списка много раз, используйте [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). Он считает один раз все вхождения всех элементов и формирует словарь счётчиков:

```
import collections

def checkio(data: list) -> list:
    c = collections.Counter(data)
    return [v for v in data if c[v] > 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Потому что `output = data` - это не копирование списка. Обе переменных будут указывать на одни и те же данные, и при модифицировании одного списка "плывёт" и другой. Т.к. после `output.pop()` элемент исчезает и из списка `data`.
Для копирования содержимого списка в другой список используется запись вида `output = data[:]` или `output = data.copy()`.

Да и вообще:

```
def checkio(data: list) -> list:
    return [el for el in data if data.count(el) > 1]
```